# Bash Script to covert rows in to columns between matching patterns

Tags: text-processing

My Input file looks like this..

```
START
line1
line2
line3
END
START
line11
line22
line33
END
```

I want my script output to be like this:

```
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

Please help.

Comment: Are there are extra lines between `END` and `START`? Is this purely a re-formatting question, or do you need to filter-out lines as well? Thx.

Comment: For a fixed number of lines per record (as shown in the question): `paste - - - - - < file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```bash
$ awk '{printf "%s", $0 (($0 == "END") ? ORS : OFS)}'
```

If you want from `START` to `END` in a line, then the following may be used:

```bash
$ awk '($0 =]"START"),($0 == "END"){printf "%s%s",$0, ($0=="END" ? ORS : OFS)}'
```

If there's `START` without `END` then the following command may be used:

```
$ awk '($0 == "START"){a="";} {a = a $0 (($0 == "END") ? "" : OFS)}  ($0 == "END"){print a}'
```

Comment: Excellent.. it worked

Comment: `+1` for an any-awk solution but notice that for the range expression you have to test for `END` twice - see [is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934486/is-a-start-end-range-expression-ever-useful-in-awk) for my and others' thoughts on range expressions if you're interested.

Comment: My issue with using a range expression is you often need to test at least one of the delimiting conditions more than once and duplicate code makes your code hard to maintain. With your new command you're testing END 3 times - I wouldn't do that. I'd use a flag for this.

Comment: I added an any-awk solution that'd handle the case of other text outside of the START-END blocks to the end of my answer to demonstrate that it doesn't require testing END more than once.

Comment: Another problem with a range expression is it'll print til the end of the input if the terminating text isn't present - try removing `END` from the end of the sample input file and then try your range-expression solution vs my flag solution. Note which one only prints text within START-END blocks :-).

Comment: TIL Don't use start end range expression. More importantly the question was asked by you on SO.

Comment: Not a problem, your first script is useful if there's always START-END blocks as the OP shows.

Comment: Edited. I got upvotes. But much of the credit to you. Learnt much of `awk` language form you. (And @αғsнιη). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS` and `RT` and assuming your data always has complete, non-nested, non-overlapping START-END blocks as shown in your example:

```
$ awk -v RS='\nEND\n' -F'\n' '{$0=$0 RT; $1=$1} 1' file
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

If you could have lines outside of START-END blocks then do this instead:

```
$ awk -v RS='\nEND\n' -F'\n' 'RT{$0=gensub(/.*\n(START\n)/,"\\1",1) RT; $1=$1; print}' file
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    $0 == "START" { f=1; rec=$0; next }
    f { rec=rec OFS $0; if ( $0 == "END" ) { print rec; f=0 } }
' file
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

If you could have nested or overlapping or incomplete START-END blocks and the above don't do what you want then you'd have to edit your question to show us those requirements.

Comment: +1. For RT of gawk.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```bash
$ sed -n -e '/^START$/ { h; d; }' -e H -e '/^END$/ { g; y/\n/ /; p; }' file
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

The `sed` script, pretty-printed with comments:

```
# Save each "START" line in the hold space and skip to the next line.
/^START$/ {
    h
    d
}

# Append all non-"START" lines to the hold space.
H

# On an "END" line, get the hold space, convert newlines to spaces, and print.
/^END$/ {
    g
    y/\n/ /
    p
}
```

This assumes non-overlapping ranges of "START" and "END" lines, and that there is no extra data between "END" and "START".

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

*To remove intervening lines between one record and the next (i.e. between  `END` and `START`):*

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'S/ <!after END> $/ / andthen do if /^START/ fff s/^END$/END\n/ {.print};'  file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'S/ <!after END> $/ / andthen print ($_ if /^START/ fff s/^END$/END\n/) ;'  file
```

Above is an answer coded in the Raku Programming Language. Briefly, the `-ne` command-line flags are used to run the code linewise over the input file, without autoprinting. Using the `S///` "big-S" substitution operator for every line that `<!after END> $` (negative lookbehind) does not end with the word `END`, add a   space. This step makes it easy to concatenate lines with whitespace in-between (note: use `\t` to get an answer similar to that posted by @Kusalananda in a comment).

Continuing, reload the `$_` topic variable with `andthen`. Now you can use Raku's sed-like `/START/ fff /STOP/` "triple-f" flip-flop operator to capture lines between the desired sentinel lines. In a formatting trick, you can actually `s/^END$/END\n/` substitute the `END` sentinel line within the same `fff` flip-flop operator, adding a `\n` newline after `END`.

Finally, the output is accomplished with Raku's humble `print` operator, which adds no newline terminator of its own, preserving the space/newline formatting above.

Sample Input:

```
START
line1
line2
line3
END
test
START
line11
line22
line33
END
```

Sample Output (removing intervening lines):

```
START line1 line2 line3 END
START line11 line22 line33 END
```

---

Now, how to preserve intervening lines? Simple: just change the `fff` flip-flop operator to accept any starting line using Raku' `*` "whatever-star". See below:

```perl
~$ raku -ne 'S/ <!after END> $/ / andthen do if * fff s/^END$/END\n/ {.print};'  file
START line1 line2 line3 END
test START line11 line22 line33 END

#OR

~$ raku -ne 'S/ <!after END> $/ / andthen print ($_ if * fff s/^END$/END\n/);'  file
START line1 line2 line3 END
test START line11 line22 line33 END
```

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/S%2F%2F%2F%20non-destructive%20substitution
https://docs.raku.org/routine/fff
https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen
https://raku.org